# R - Converting a Function to String

Tags: r

I am working on a function that would behave similar to `Reduce` where you pass in a function and dispatch it over the arguments.  Here is simple example to demonstrate what I am working on.

```
fun <- function(f){

    switch(f,
           `+` = "addition",
           stop("undefined")
    )
}

fun(`+`)
```

Now this clearly won't work as it stands because `switch` requires a `character` or `numeric` `EXPR`.  What I don't know how to do is convert the function `f` that is passed to `fun` to a `string`.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what exactly you're trying to do here, but maybe `match.fun()` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @joran thanks but that doesn't solve the problem, same error as above.  I want in this case the function to return `"addition"` where the `switch` statement is dispatching on the function passed to it.

Comment: Ah, that was apparently what I was not understanding in my original reading.

Comment: Are you expecting the function's input to always be enclosed in backticks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to capture the input and deparse the call.

```
fun <- function(f){
  switch(deparse(substitute(f)),
         `+` = "addition",
         stop("undefined")
  )
}

fun(`+`)
#[1] "addition"
```

Comment: Probably the best solution. To my knowledge, R cannot logically compare two functions. For example, if you assign `my.fun <- mean`, the comparison `my.fun == mean` does not work.

Comment: You can test the equality of functions `identical(my.fun, mean) [1] TRUE`

Answer (score -1):

Going off of Pierre's comment above, one can use `identical` to test whether two functions are the same. This doesn't work well with `switch`, but an if/else tree is still relatively simple:

```
fun <- function(f) {
    if (identical(f, `+`)) {
        return('addition')
    } else if (identical(f, mean)) {
        return('mean')
    } else {
        return('undefined')
    }
}
```